# Complex Integration and holomorphic primitive

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, definite-integrals, contour-integration

> (a) Let $γ_1 = [1, 0] ∪ [0, i]$. 
>   Compute $\int_{γ1} \bar{z} dz$.
>
> (b) Let $C$ be the circle of radius $1$ and center $0$, and let $γ_2$ be the
>    (smaller) arc of $C$ joining the points $1$ and $i$. 
>   Compute $\int_{γ_2} \bar{z} dz$.
>
> (c) Only based on (a), (b), can we tell that $\bar{z} $ does not admit a holomorphic primitive on $\mathbb C$?

My attempts:

a) Let $z = x+iy$, then $\bar{z} = x-iy$ and so 
$$
\int_{γ1} \bar{z} dz = \int_1^0 x dz + i \int_1^0 - y dz + \int_0^i x dz + i \int_0^i - y dz = x+y + i(x-y)
$$

b) $$\int_{γ_2} \bar{z} dz = \int_0^1 x dz + i \int_0^1 - y dz = x-iy$$

c) I'm not sure about it, but I think that yes, we can tell that it doesn't admit a holomorphic primitive on $\mathbb C$ since the integral in part a) and b) are not equal.

Comment: If $z \mapsto \bar{z}$ had a holomorphic primitive then the integral over any closed curve would be zero.

Comment: So the answer to part c) is yes? And are my answers to parts a) and b) correct?

Comment: Not sure where you are getting your calculation in part (b).  Does the question not call for an integral over a quarter circle?

Comment: $\displaystyle \int_0^\frac{\pi}{2} ( e^{-i\theta} )(i e^{i\theta} d\theta) = \frac{ i\pi}{2}.$

Comment: Both parts (a) and (b), the answer is a complex number, not involving $x$ and $y$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your answers to (a) and (b) don't make sense, since an integral is a *number*.

Concerning (a), we have\begin{align}\int_{\gamma_1}\overline z\,\mathrm dz&=\int_0^1-t\,\mathrm dt+\int_0^1(it)\times i\,\mathrm dt\\&=-1.\end{align}And, concerning (b), we have\begin{align}\int_{\gamma_2}\overline z\,\mathrm dz&=\int_0^{\pi/2}e^{-it}\times ie^{it}\,\mathrm dt\\&=\frac{i\pi}2.\end{align}

Since this gives you distinct numbers, the conjugation does *not* admit a holomorphic primitive.

Comment: In part a), you only integrated over [1,0], what about [0,i]? And could you please provide me with more steps for part a)?

Comment: No, I don't integrate only over $[1,0]$. What I have is a sum, right?! The first summand concerns $[1,0]$, whereas the second one concerns $[0,i]$.